# Error en condición if cuando compruebo si existe un archivo antes de seguir con la función

Tags: python, funciones, condiciones

¡Buenas tardes!

Estoy intentando hacer un programa donde un usuario pueda crear un perfil, modificarlo, verlo, etc. y esos datos los pueda guardar en un archivo.

Todo iba bastante bien, hasta que me he atascado en esta parte. Es decir, el programa me funcionaba correctamente si no guardaba los datos, pero al querer complicarlo con esta parte no consigo los resultados deseados en la función de Crear_perfil (bueno, ni en ninguna de las siguientes funciones en cuestión). La condición "if... else" no funciona como esperaba y no sé muy bien por qué. ¿Alguien me puede echar una mano?

Os dejo aquí parte del código del programa:

```
    import os
    
    def preguntar_opcion():
        # Función para imprimir el menú y devolver la opción elegida por el usuario
        print("\nMENÚ\n")
        print("******************")
        print("Si quieres crear tu perfil de usuario, pulsa 1.")
        print("Si ya tiene un perfil y lo quieres modificar, pulsa 2.")
        print("Si quieres ver tu perfil, pulsa 3.")
        print("Si quieres actualizar la serie que estás viendo ahora, pulsa 4.")
        print("Si quieres salir, pulsa 5.")
    
        opcion = int(input("\n¿Qué te gustaría hacer?\n"))
        print("\n******************\n")
        return opcion 
    
    def pedir_datos():
        # Función para pedir los datos del usuario y devolverlos
        nombre = input("¿Cómo te llamas? ").capitalize()
        apellido1 = input("¿Cuál es tu primer apellido?: ").capitalize()
        apellido2 = input("¿Y el segundo?: ").capitalize()
        anho = int(input("¿En qué año naciste? "))
        edad = 2022 - anho
        edad = str(edad)

        return nombre, apellido1, apellido2, edad
    
    def imprimir_datos(nombre, apellido1, apellido2, edad):
        # Función para imprimir los datos del perfil del usuario
        perfil = nombre, apellido1, apellido2, edad
        print()
        print("Nombre:", nombre, apellido1, apellido2)
        print("Edad:", edad, "años")
        
        return perfil   
    
    def guardar_datos(nombre, apellido1, apellido2, edad):
        # Guarda los datos del usuario en un archivo
        archivo = open(nombre + ".user", "w", encoding = "UTF-8")
        archivo.write(nombre + "\n" + apellido1 + "\n" + apellido2 + "\n" + edad + "\n")
        archivo.close()

def crear_perfil():
    # Función que comprueba si existe ya un archivo con ese nombre de usuario. Si no existe: llama a pedir_datos(), imprime el mensaje de perfil creado y llama a imprimir_datos()
    continuar = True
    while continuar:
    nombre = input("¿Cómo te llamas? ").capitalize()
    if os.path.isfile(nombre + ".user"): 
        nombre, apellido1, apellido2, edad = pedir_datos()
        guardar_datos(nombre, apellido1, apellido2, edad)
        print("\nTu perfil ha sido creado.\n")
        imprimir_datos(nombre, apellido1, apellido2, edad)
    else:
        print("Ya existe un perfil con ese nombre.")
        continuar = False
```

¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: `if not os.path.isfile(nombre + ".user"):`

Comment: Gracias por el comentario. Esa opción ya la había explorado, pero no conseguí nada nuevo. Me devuelve este error: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 7)

Comment: Pero ese es otro error, debido a que `pedir_datos()`  devuelve una 5-tupla y tú solo recuperas cuatro valores (te falta `estatura`). La línea correcta es `nombre, apellido1, apellido2, edad, estatura = pedir_datos()`

Comment: Muchas gracias de nuevo. Cierto, eso lo he arreglado, pero como es un int me dice que no lo puede concatenar. He intentado convertirlo a string, pero me sigue dando el error: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str. Además, ahora me he dado cuenta que tal y como tengo el código me devuelve dos veces ¿"Cómo te llamas? ¿Cómo podría hacer para evitar ese problema? ¡Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: ` + str(edad) ` Pues conviertelo a string ...

Comment: Ah, tienes mal la ubicación de `continuar = False`. Debería estar en el bloque `True` del `if`. Como ya lograstes crear la cuenta, no es necesario "continuar" ...

Comment: Sí, me he dado cuenta de eso, ¡muchas gracias por ayudarme! He arreglado ya unas cuantas cosillas, aunque de momento sigo atascada en esto: nombre = input("¿Cómo te llamas? ").capitalize() porque, claro, tal y como lo tengo, el programa pregunta dos veces al usuario Cómo se llama.